# Combine PSObject regex filtered results with initial value names

Tags: powershell, properties, pipe, psobject

Need to search some string data in USERS properties inside my AD. I belive that I've made the first step and found them, but I've some troubles with combining the results in one table - I need to determine the CN or Name of the user (something to distinguish the object).
Here's the code to search from 12 to 16 characters in any string properties:

```
$search = 'OU=root,DC=contoso,DC=com'
$props =    @(
            'CN',
            'City',
            'Company',
            'Department',
            'Description',
            'Division',
            'Fax',
            'HomeDirectory',
            'Homepage',
            'HomePhone',
            'Initials',
            'MobilePhone',
            'Office',
            'OfficePhone',
            'Organization',
            'OtherName',
            'POBox',
            'PostalCode',
            'State',
            'StreetAddress',
            'Title'
            )
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $search | Select $props |
%{$_.psobject.properties} | 
?{$_.Value -match "(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{12,16}"} | 
Format-Table @{N='CN';E={$_.CN}},Name,Value -AutoSize
```

This gives me the table:

```
CN      Name        Value
____    ____        _____
        Description 2f565#124s$Dsa
```

I understand that the pipe doesn't hold CN by its end. 
I've tried to use foreach-object but failed to rewrite correctly all functions (e.g. psobject.properties) with maintaining the pipe.
I need something like:

```
(User)CN                                        PropName        Value
CN=bradpitt,OU=Users,OU=root,DC=contoso,DC=com  Description     2f565#124s$Dsa
```

Comment: Insert into your ForEach at begin `{$CN=$_.CN;...}` and in the `Format-Table @{N='CN';E={$CN}}`

Comment: Like this? `Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $search | Select $props | ForEach-Object { $CN=$_.CN | %{$_.psobject.properties} | ?{$_.Value -match "(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{6,20}"} | Format-Table @{N='CN';E={$CN}},Name,Value -AutoSize }` - gives nothing(

Comment: no that was a semicolon `;` try `ForEach{$CN=$_.CN;$_.psobject.properties} | `

Comment: It WORKED! Thank you! Sorry for possible silly questions previously, but i'm not a coder - just grabbed some scripts and merged it. Overall we'll have this:
`Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $search | Select $props |
            ForEach-Object { $CN=$_.CN ; $_.psobject.properties} |
?{$_.Value -match "(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{12,16}"} | Format-Table @{N='CN';E={$CN}},Name,Value -AutoSize`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to LotPings, this is the working result, that searches from 12 to 16 characters (regex means: at least - one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character):

```
$search = 'OU=root,DC=contoso,DC=com'
$props =    @(
            'City',
            'Company',
            'Department',
            'Description',
            'Division',
            'Fax',
            'HomeDirectory',
            'Homepage',
            'HomePhone',
            'Initials',
            'MobilePhone',
            'Office',
            'OfficePhone',
            'Organization',
            'OtherName',
            'POBox',
            'PostalCode',
            'State',
            'StreetAddress',
            'Title'
            )
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $search | Select $props |
            ForEach-Object { $CN=$_.CN ; $_.psobject.properties} |
?{$_.Value -match "(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{12,16}"} | Format-Table @{N='CN';E={$CN}},Name,Value -AutoSize
```